# Cannot make my sample function async

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

Just began playing around with Js and Node a bit. I have the following code snippet below in which libFunction is supposed to work asynchronously. Yeah, you guessed it, it is working synchronously.

"print from callback" is printed before "print from main". Where do you think I am messing up ? Thanks

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec

function blocking()
{
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < start + 5000);
} 

function libFunction(callback)
{
    exec(blocking(), callback("print from callback"));
}

function callback(txt)
{
    console.log(txt);
}

libFunction(callback);

console.log("print from main");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this type of code to make non-blocking calls.

```
function libFunction(callback)
{
    setTimeout(function(){callback("print from callback");}, 5000);
}
```

In function `blocking`  `while` loop obviously **is** blocking, so program does nothing before 5 seconds are finished. Node.js is not multithreaded so print from main waites print from callback to finish.

*Note* that the assumption that `exec` is asynchronronious is wrong and the assumption that it starts a new tread is even wronger - javascript is not multithreaded at all (not counting `Worker`s).

On the other hand call to `setTimeout` is asynchronious

Comment: Thanks for that! It works. But I still do not get it. I thought using 'exec' meant my blocking function would be launched in a seperate thread. Unless I'm implicitly waiting for the thread to finish ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes here.

`exec` is for executing child processes, not running in-process javascript code. It expects a string, but your code is giving it `undefined`. It also expects a callback function, but you are also giving it undefined because your are **invoking** the callback yourself instead of just **passing** it to `exec`. Be really careful about `someFunction(arg1, callback)` (no parentheses) vs. `someFunction(arg1, callback())` (parentheses). Completely different!

If you want to experiment with asynchronous functions and callbacks, use `setTimeout` like in the example @sasha.sochka posted.

Comment: Okies! I messed up the 'exec' call. Thanks for clearing that up